# Spilting tables up at wrong place when using an if and while loop

Tags: mysql, if-statement, pdo, while-loop, html-table

I'm trying to show 2 tables, 1 for shows and 1 for movies but at the moment it shows 1 table per record

Here's the page http://starsqa.com/ana-lucasey-about

Here's the new code snippet:

```
  if ($result['order'] == 1 OR $result['order'] == 2 OR $result['order'] == 6 OR $result['order'] == 4) {
            $qry_stringr = "SELECT roles.starID, starName, roles.knownFor, roles.`character`, roles.`year`, most, type FROM roles INNER JOIN stars ON roles.starID = stars.starID WHERE roles.starID = {$result['starID']} ORDER BY roles.`year` DESC";
            $prepr = $pdo_conn->prepare($qry_stringr);
            $prepr->execute(array());

        $showsArray = array();
        $moviesArray = array();

 while ($rowr = $prepr->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      if ($rowr['type'] == 0) {
         $showsArray[] = $rowr;
      }
      else if($rowr['type'] == 1) {
         $moviesArray[] = $rowr;
      }
 }
echo "<table border='1' bgColor='white'><tbody><tr bgColor='lightgrey' style='color:black;'><td><b>Show</b></td><td><b>Role</b></td><td><b>Year</b></td></tr>";
 foreach($showsArray as $row) {
                    $most = $rowr['most'] == 1 ? ' color:#DE5635;' : '' OR $rowr['most'] == 0 ? ' color:black;' : '';
                    echo "<tr><td><font style='{$most}'>{$rowr['knownFor']}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
                          <td><font style='{$most}'>{$rowr['character']}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
                          <td><font style='{$most}'>{$rowr['year']}</font></td></tr>";
                    echo "</tbody>";
 }
 echo "</table><br><br>";
echo "<table border='1' bgColor='white'><tbody><tr bgColor='lightgrey' style='color:black;'><td><b>Movie</b></td><td><b>Role</b></td><td><b>Year</b></td></tr>";
 foreach($moviesArray as $row) {
                    $most = $rowr['most'] == 1 ? ' color:#DE5635;' : '' OR $rowr['most'] == 0 ? ' color:black;' : '';
                    echo "<tr><td><font style='{$most}'>{$rowr['knownFor']}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
                          <td><font style='{$most}'>{$rowr['character']}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
                          <td><font style='{$most}'>{$rowr['year']}</font></td></tr>";
                    echo "</tbody>";
 }
 echo "</table><br><br>"; 
 }
```

Comment: This question is too localized to be asked on this site. Although it will probably get an answer from some volunteer who have a spare time, but in general a programmer is supposed to debug their code oneself, not asking a community to do it for them.

Comment: I'm new at coding and I have been trying to figured it out for a good few hours and I thought maybe a fresh set of eyes would be able to spot my mistake.

Comment: That's the very point. Stack Overflow site is not a forum and asking for the fresh pair of eyes is against the rules. Yet a programmer have to *run* their code, not watch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a table for each row.  If you look in your while loop, you can see that for each iteration of your data, you're creating a new table.  There are a number of ways to fix this, I would create two arrays, one for shows and one for movies.  During your loop, add the row to the appropriate array.  After all that, loop through each array to create your tables.

For example:

```
 $showsArray = array();
 $moviesArray = array();

 while ($rowr = $prepr->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      if ($rowr['type'] == 0) {
         $showsArray[] = $rowr;
      }
      elseif($rowr['type'] == 1) {
         $moviesArray[] = $rowr;
      }
 }
 echo "<table border='1' bgColor='white'><tbody><tr bgColor='lightgrey' style='color:black;'><td><b>Show</b></td><td><b>Role</b></td><td><b>Year</b></td></tr>";
 foreach($showsArray as $row) {
     //create the table row here.
 }
 echo "</table>";
echo "<table border='1' bgColor='white'><tbody><tr bgColor='lightgrey' style='color:black;'><td><b>Movie</b></td><td><b>Role</b></td><td><b>Year</b></td></tr>";
 foreach($moviesArray as $row) {
     //create the table row here.
 }
 echo "</table>";
```

Another way to do this is during the while loop, instead of using echo, append the HTML to a variable and then output it after the loop.

```
$movies = "";
$shows = "";
while ($rowr = $prepr->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "{$rowr['type']} - {$rowr['knownFor']} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        if ($rowr['type'] == 0) {
            $shows .= "<tr><td><font>{$rowr['knownFor']}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
                  <td><font>{$rowr['character']}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
                  <td><font>{$rowr['year']}</font></td></tr>";
            $shows .= "</tbody></table><br><br>";
        }
        if ($rowr['type'] == 1) {
            $movies .= "<tr><td><font>{$rowr['knownFor']}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
                  <td><font>{$rowr['character']}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
                  <td><font>{$rowr['year']}</font></td></tr>";
            $movies .= "</tbody></table>";
        }
    }
   //add code here to create your
   //tables and echo $shows and $movies in the appropriate places.
```

Comment: ok thanks, trying both of those ways now, i'll let you know which one works best for me or if i have any issues with them

Comment: first way, soo close it's showing the rows just no characters are showing up, I have changed my code snippet to show the new code i'm using incase I have done something wrong along the way

Comment: You're looping through your array creating one called $row, but referring to $rowr to generate the html.  You need to use `foreach($moviesArray as $rowr)`

Comment: wait found a issue, if they have no movies, I have moved the movie to shows, how would I hide the headings for movies it's still showing up?